# How to collect the negative eigenvalues of a matrix?

Tags: plotting, matrix, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

I want to plot `Sum[E[i]]` verseus `t` where `E[i]` are the negative eigenvalues of the matrix:

```
M1 = {{5 t, 0, 0, t^2}, {0, -30 + t, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -30 + t, 0}, {t^2, 
   0, 0, 1 + 2 t}}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Plot[Evaluate[Eigenvalues[M1]], {t, 0, 10}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

```
sumofnegativeeigenvalues = Total @ - Ramp @ - Eigenvalues[M1]
```

> ```
> -2 Ramp[30 - t] - 
>  Ramp[1/2 (-1 - 7 t - Sqrt[1 - 6 t + 9 t^2 + 4 t^4])] - 
>  Ramp[1/2 (-1 - 7 t + Sqrt[1 - 6 t + 9 t^2 + 4 t^4])]
> ```

```
Plot[sumofnegativeeigenvalues, {t, 0, 10}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
ClearAll[sumNegEigenVals]
sumNegEigenVals = Eigenvalues /* Minus /* Ramp /* Minus /* Total;

sumNegEigenVals @ M1 == sumofnegativeeigenvalues
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: Not going to lie, I've just had to figure out what `@ -` means.